# Can anybody explain constraint relation for this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

> The question is - Two particles of masses $m$ and $2m$ are placed on a smooth horizontal table. A string which joins these two masses, hangs over the edge supporting a pulley, which suspends a particle of mass $3m$. The pulley has negligible mass. The two parts of the string on the table are parallel and perpendicular to the edge of the table. The hanging parts parts of the string are vertical. Find the acceleration of the particle of mass $3m$.

MY ANSWER- I know that the acceleration of one string will be double of the other and due to behaviour of frictionless pulley the acceleration of pulley will be 3a/2. But can anybody explain me how to write Co-ordinate functions for such a system. Is it impossible?

Comment: I think it is nothing but work done. $T_1x_1=T_x_2$

Comment: Please explain by using co-ordinate functions only.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
In the question object 1 and object 2 are moving towards right side ,so X1 and X2 are decreasing thus a1 and a2 are negative.But Y3 is increasing as it going down thus a3 is possitive.

The relations found here are constrains for the question. Now we can easily found the value of acceleration by solving force equation of each masses using these constrains.

Comment: You got the question wrongly. It is my fault that I did not draw the figure. Sorry for that. Actually in the actual diagram they are not connected in series as you have drawn but in parallel. If they were in series then the question was easy. The string extends from one block and then goes through a pulley and then to another block.

Answer (score 0):

The tension in the upper string must be the same on both sides of the pulley, so a1 does equal 2 (a2).  If one side of the upper string drops by two units, the pulley drops by one, so the acceleration of the pulley (and the lower mass) = a3  =(3/2)a2.
Then for the lower mass:   3mg – 2T = (3m) a3  = (3m)(3/2)a2    Putting in T = (2m)a2  yields a2 = (6/17) g,  a1 = (12/17) g,   a3 = (9/17) g  and  T = (12/17) mg